# Usage of '' it '' in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality

I wonder if i can use '' it '' and verb+ing in the sentences below. I know that ''it'' can be used between verb and adjctive . Can use it in the same way in sentences below?

1) I left it as legacy to you to find treasury .

2) I left finding treasury as legacy to you.

Comment: It's likely that you are confusing **treasury** with **treasure**. (Most likely, you mean to say *I left* the ***treasure*** *as a legacy for you to find.*)

Comment: It was my fault but turkish-english dictionary says both has same meaning . This is why i use that.

Comment: You can use **treasury** in this way, but then it's a singular count noun: "...to find **the** treasury."  This usage of **treasury** is uncommon outside of governmental situations though and sounds unnatural unless you are specifically talking about the accumulated wealth of a nation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I don't know what your sentences are supposed to mean. Are you using the correct vocabulary when you say 'legacy' and 'treasury'?

Instead I'll use a different sentence in the hope that it helps to answer your question.

I left it to you to clean the car. (correct)

I left cleaning the car to you. (correct)

Comment: I mean i wonder if i can use “ finding treasury” instead of something in the same way in  “ leave something as legacy” .

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you are confusing **treasury** with **treasure**. A *treasury* is a building that manufactures money. A *treasure* is a hidden cache of valuable goods.

If so, neither sentence is natural. The most likely phrasing would be something like:

> I left the *treasure* as a legacy for you to find.

Since you specify *treasure* (and *to find*) already, there is no reason to use the pronoun *it*—unless it is referring to something in a previous sentence.

---

However, if you don't specify *treasure*, you can say:

> I left **it** as a legacy for you to find.

You could even use drop both things:

> I left **it** as a legacy for you.

That would leave it ambiguous if a previous sentence is talking about treasure, finding it, or both.